# on the spectral norm of the inverse of a random matrix

Tags: random-matrices

I have the following problem.
A is a sum of independent random matrices and B is some fixed positive (semi-)definite matrix.
I'm interested in a bound on the expectation of the operator norm $\lVert BA(I+BA)^{-1}\rVert$. Is there anything easy to say about this ? Alternatively $\lVert (I+BA)^{-1}\rVert$ should do it as well.

Comment: Is there a particular distribution you are choosing the random matrices from?

Comment: well i wouldn't want to use that type of information if possible but gaussian with some non-linearities on top.